# Return a column value every n number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple select on a table which does not have a primary key. I am extracting 365 values, one for each day of the year.  Is it possible for me to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2. I wish to add another column called rain and populate it with a value one per week, or every seven rows.  my current query is:

```
SELECT jDay, tMax, tMin 
FROM tableName;
```

It's returning just the first three columns. How do I achieve the rain column to make it look like this:

```
jDAy   tmax    tmin    rain
11    21.1    10.1     0     
12    22.1    11.1     0 
13    23.1     9.1     0 
14    24.1     8.1     0 
15    29.1    10.1     0 
16    21.1    11.1     0 
17    22.1    12.1     4
```

Edited: the solution thanks to ZLK:

```
SELECT 
    julDay, tMax, tMin, 
    rain = case 
              when row_number() over (order by julDay) % 7 = 0 then 4 
              else 0 
           end
FROM
    tableName 
WHERE
    .......;
```

Comment: Something like `rain = case when row_number() over (order by jday) % 7 = 0 then myval else 0 end`

Comment: Thank you, works perfect!  I thought it needed a primary key to use row_number.   Do you know of any inbuilt SQL feature to turn a julian day value into a date of the current year?   e.g 9 would be 09/01/yyyy?  Thanks again

Comment: Perhaps [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) is something like what you're looking for. The current year/month values could be derived from `DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())` and `DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())`. **EDIT:** I just realised this is for SQL 2008, in which case you'd need to do it manually. e.g. `CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(JDAY AS VARCHAR(2))`

Comment: How do I accept this as an answer since is was a reply and not an answer?

Comment: I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with [`MODULO (%)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx), you can specify a value every X rows.

e.g.

```
SELECT julDay,
       tMax,
       tMin,
       rain = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY julDay) % 7 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END
FROM tableName;
```